# Diophantine $7^a+2=3^b$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I want to find the solutions $(a,b)\in\mathbb{Z}^+\times\mathbb{Z}^+$ of $7^a+2=3^b$. One such solution is $(a,b)=(1,2)$.

Looking modulo $4$, we have $(-1)^a+2\equiv(-1)^b$, so $a$ and $b$ are of different parity.

Modulo $3$: $1+2\equiv 0$, which is always true.

Modulo $7$: $2\equiv 3^b$, so $b\equiv 2\pmod 6$. This means $a$ is odd.

Comment: Doing arithmetic modulo $\;9\;$ one gets that it must be $\;a=1\pmod 3\;$, otherwise the left side isn't zero modulo $\;9\;$ , whereas the right one obviously is.

Comment: This is the [German 2010 VAIMO 1 problem 3](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?f=56&t=418604&).

Comment: I rewrite the equation $7^a=3^b-2$ and calculate $a=log((3^b-2)/log(7)$ and calculate the discrepancy $d=3^b-floor ((7^( log((3^b-2)+2)/log(7))$ which is a measure of the distance from $3^b$ to the nearest $7^a+2$. 
I note that for b=2,3,4,...... the discrepancy is increasing but there seems to be an anomaly for (at least some) values of b near $b=2^n$ such as b=9,32,62,125,248,512  (but also others like b=39 and 48) where the value is not increasing, indicating a relation to the related equation $7^a+2=(3^2)^b=9^b$. I realize this is a little beside the point.

Comment: Your question is similar to a question what I have posted here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/508714/solving-the-equation-x2-7y-2 . But these two equations have something different.

Comment: I've written a loong answer at the current ***duplicate-question***, see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2272949/1714 . Perhaps it should be transferred to this earlier question?

Comment: Searching [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%247%5Ex%2B2%3D3%5Ey%24&p=1) also returns [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1551324/exponential-diophantine-equation-7y-2-3x).