# Solving equation with two unknown degrees

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility, diophantine-equations

I sticked at this problem:
$3^x-7^y=2$ where it should be solved for natural $x$ and $y$.
I made the conclusion that $x=12a+2$ and $y=6b+1$ after playing with different mods. I am sure that the only solution is $x=2$ and $y=1$ as wolfram alpha confirmed it. Can you help with proof for this?

Comment: If you say that $x$ is of the form $x=6a+1$ how can you get $x=2$ then?

Comment: Sorry, I meant x=12a+2

Comment: Wolfram alpha cannot guarantee to fully solve such equations. What makes it extremely likely, that there is no additional solution, is that $7^y+2$ is not a perfect power for the integers $y$ in then range $[2,10^5]$ , which I verified with pari/gp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x>2$ and $y>1$.

Thus, our equation it's $$3^x-9=7^x-7$$ or
$$9\left(3^{x-2}-1\right)=7\left(7^{y-1}-1\right),$$
which says that $3^{x-2}-1$ is divisible by $7$, which gives $x-2$ is divisible by $6,$

which gives $3^{x-2}-1$ is divisible by $3^6-1=8\cdot7\cdot13,$ which gives $7^{y-1}-1$ is divisible by $13$,

which says $y-1$ is divisible by $12$, which says $7^{y-1}-1$ is divisible by $7^{12}-1=2^5\cdot3^2\cdot5^2\cdot13\cdot19\cdot181,$

which says $3^{x-2}-1$ is divisible by $19$, which gives $x-2$ is divisible by $18$, which says

$3^{x-2}-1$ is divisible by $3^{18}-1,$ which is divisible by $37$, which gives $7^{y-1}-1$ is divisible by $37$,

which gives $y-1$ is divisible by $9$, which says that $7^{y-1}-1$ is divisible by $7^9-1$, which is divisible by $27$,

which says $9\left(3^{x-2}-1\right)$ is divisible by $27$, which is a contradiction.

Id est, our equation has no solutions for $x\geq3$ and $y\geq2$.

Can you end it now?

Comment: Thank you, very much! May I ask why the fact that 6|x-2 makes 3^(x-2)-1 divisible by 3^6-1 and so on? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Because $3^{6n}-1=(3^6)^n-1=(3^6-1)(3^{6n-6}+...+1)$ is divisible by $3^6-1.$

Answer (score 1):

Say $y\geq 2$ then $7^y\equiv _{49} 0$ so we have to solve $$3^x\equiv _{49} 2$$

It is not difficult to see $ 3^5\equiv _{49} -2$ and $3^{21}\equiv _{49} -1$, so $$3^{x-26}\equiv _{49} 1$$

and $\color{red}{\rm ord _{49}(3)=42 }$ so $42\mid x-26$ and thus $x=42z+26$ for some integer $z$. Now we have $$3^{26}\cdot (3^{42})^z\equiv _{43} 7^y+2$$

Since $3^{26}\equiv _{43} 15$ and $3^{42}\equiv _{43} 1$ we have to solve $$7^y\equiv _{43} 13$$

Since $7^y \pmod{43}\in \{1,7,6,-1,-7-6\}$  we see that we have no solution for $y\geq 2$.

Comment: Any way, I solved recently similar problem here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3256556/solve-for-integer-m-n-2m-3n-5/3256567#3256567 on the same way.