# Proving that the equation $11^x - 3^y = 2$ has only one integer solution

Tags: number-theory

I've found that $x = 2a + 1$, $y = 2 + 5b$, where a and b are natural numbers including zero. How to continue proving this?

Comment: If $x>1$ then $3^y = -2 \pmod{121}$ has a solution. Try small powers of $3$ until you see why this equation can't have a solution.

Comment: This hint actually leads to the solution, but how can we see without computer help that $$3^y\equiv -2\mod 121$$ is impossible ?

Comment: Ah, OK , the order is very small ! This is what I missed !

Comment: @Peter  write $11 \left( 11^x - 1 \right)  = 9 \left( 3^y - 1 \right).$ ASSUME that $x,y>0$ since $3^y \equiv 1 \pmod {11}$   we find that $y$ is divisible by $5. \; $ Then $3^y-1$  is divisble by $3^5 - 1 = 2 \cdot 11^2.$  But then we see $11 \left( 11^x - 1 \right)$ is divisible by $11^2,$  which CONTRADICTS $x > 0$   I put numerous examples at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1941354/elementary-solution-of-exponential-diophantine-equation-2x-3y-7