Powers of $19$ and $17$ differ by $2$
Solve the equation
$$19^x=17^y+2$$
over the positive integers.
This is strangely nonstandard (since working mod powers of $17$ or $19$ does not work). I think working in $\mathbb{Z}\left[\sqrt{2}\right]$ might be useful.

I suspect the trick is to prove $y=x=1$ is the only solution you have without contradiction.. There's a similar problem : Prove $x^3-y^2=2$ only happens for $x=3, y=5$ Of course that is find the base and not find the exponents.

Welcome to Math SE. FYI, using an Approach0 search, there's the AoPS thread Diophantine Equation.

@JohnOmielan  there is a method, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1941354/elementary-solution-of-exponential-diophantine-equation-2x-3y-7/1942409#1942409  and a dozen others

@JohnOmielan  got it finally

Please avoid opinion-based  terms in the title.

Got it, took a while.
We write
$$  19 (19^u - 1) = 17 ( 17^v -1)  $$
We ASSUME $u$ and $v$ are nonzero, that is $u \geq 1$ and $v \geq 1$.
Steps...  we need $19^u \equiv 1 \pmod {17}.$  Thus
$$  8 | u  $$
We check, $19^8 - 1$  is divisible by $181,$  thus $19^u - 1$ is divisible by $181.$
We need $17^v \equiv 1 \pmod {181}.$
Thus
$$  36 | v  $$
We check, $17^{36} - 1$  is divisible by $307,$  thus $17^v - 1$ is divisible by $307.$
We need $19^u \equiv 1 \pmod {307}.$  Thus
$$  51 | u  $$  and especially
$$  17 | u  $$
So far, we have $u$ divisible by both $8$ and $17$  so it is divisible by $136.$
We check, $19^{136} - 1$  is divisible by $17^2$  thus $19^u - 1$ is divisible by $17^2.$
However, the original way I wrote this was
$$  19 (19^u - 1) = 17 ( 17^v -1)  $$
ASSUMING $u$ and $v$ are nonzero.
Once $v \geq 1$ we see $17^v - 1 $  is NOT divisible by $17,$  so $17 ( 17^v -1)  $  is NOT divisible by $17^2.$
This contradiction shows that the assumption is false, indeed  $v=0$
P.S.  we could have stuck with smaller exponents  in places. For example we did not need to  keep the exponent $36,$  actually $17^3 - 1$  is divisible by $307$ because $17^2 + 17 + 1 = 289 + 17 + 1 = 290 +17 = 307$
$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$
Illustrations of the method, learned from a 2015 answer  by
https://math.stackexchange.com/users/292972/gyumin-roh
Exponential Diophantine equation $7^y + 2 = 3^x$
Gyumin Roh answer from 2015
Elementary solution of exponential Diophantine equation $2^x - 3^y = 7$.
Elementary solution of exponential Diophantine equation $2^x - 3^y = 7$.  ME!  41, 31, 241, 17
Finding solutions to the diophantine equation $7^a=3^b+100$   343 - 243 =
100
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2100780/is-2m-1-ever-a-power-of-3-for-m-3/2100847#2100847
The diophantine equation $5\times 2^{x-4}=3^y-1$
Equation in integers $7^x-3^y=4$
Solve in $\mathbb N^{2}$ the following equation : $5^{2x}-3\cdot2^{2y}+5^{x}2^{y-1}-2^{y-1}-2\cdot5^{x}+1=0$
Solve Diophantine equation: $2^x=5^y+3$ for non-negative integers $x,y$.  128 - 125 = 3
Diophantine equation power of 7 and 2
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3873689/find-natural-numbers-a-b-such-that-3a-2b-1  did +-1
Finding all natural $x$, $y$, $z$ satisfying $7^x+1=3^y+5^z$
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4155854/how-do-we-find-all-k-s-in-mathbbn-where-5s-2-3k/4156003#4156003 5-3=2
Exponential diophantine equation $2^x+7^y=9^z$.
