# Find all integer numbers $k$,$l$,$m$,$n$ for which $3^k$ • $5^l$ + $7^m$ = $2^n$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

> Find all integer numbers $k$,$l$,$m$,$n$ for which $3^k\cdot  5^l+7^m=2^n$.

I tried to find a decent modulo and look at ending digits, but nothing more. Thank you for your responses. 
Obviously is $k$ = $l$ = $m$ = $0$ and $n$ = $1$ a solution.

Comment: There are also $k=l=1,m=0, n=4$ and $k=l=0,m=1,n=3$ and $k=0,l=2,m=1,n=5$  As a practical matter, I would just write a program to check $k,l,m$ up to $10$ and assume there are no larger because perfect powers are so rare.

Comment: (A) where did you get the problem? (B) what assurance do you have that there is an elementary solution?

Answer (score 2):

From Robert's list: there is an elementary method to find all solutions to, say,
$$ 2^n - 7^m = 15. $$ Evidently we need to solve the same problem when replacing $15$ by these $1,3,5,9,15, 25.$ I do not see any reason to expect a proof that $k+l \leq 2.$

For the six problems mentioned, see

[Exponential Diophantine equation $7^y + 2 = 3^x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1551324/exponential-diophantine-equation-7y-2-3x)

[Elementary solution of exponential Diophantine equation $2^x - 3^y = 7$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1941354/elementary-solution-of-exponential-diophantine-equation-2x-3y-7)

[Elementary solution of exponential Diophantine equation $2^x - 3^y = 7$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1941354/elementary-solution-of-exponential-diophantine-equation-2x-3y-7/1942409#1942409)

[Finding solutions to the diophantine equation $7^a=3^b+100$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1946621/finding-solutions-to-the-diophantine-equation-7a-3b100/1946810#1946810)

Gottfried Helms came up with a different algorithm that allowed him to solve problems where my numbers got too big.

Answer (score 1):

I find the following values:
$$ \matrix{ k & l & m & n\cr0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \cr
0 & 0 & 1 & 3 \cr
0 & 2 & 1 & 5 \cr
1 & 0 & 0 & 2 \cr
1 & 1 & 0 & 4 \cr
1 & 1 & 2 & 6 \cr
2 & 0 & 1 & 4 \cr
}$$
These are the only ones with $0 \le k,l,m \le 100$.

Comment: But I need a more Mathematical solution though

Answer (score 1):

let (1): $3^k 5^l+7^m=2^n$ (supposing that k and l are greater or equal to 1).
Studying the equation modulo 3, you see that n is even, $n=2n'$. Studying now the equation at modulo 5, you see too that $n-m = 4a$, for some $a$. Pass the 7^m to the right, factorize and observe that $2^{n'}-7^{2a-n'}$ and $2^{n'}+7^{2a-n'}$ are coprime. The rest its  easy and you can finish without much dificulty.

Comment: I will not post the rest of the answer, because this would consume a bit more of tim, and i got to go. i hope that i can help you later.

Comment: Wrong.  There are solutions for both odd and even $n$, but $n$ is even if $k > 0$.

Comment: you're right. My gap was suppose that k and l was greater then 1.

Comment: Shouldn't n be even?