# The diophantine equation $5\times 2^{x-4}=3^y-1$

Tags: diophantine-equations, exponential-diophantine-equations

I have this question: can we deduce directly using the Catalan conjecture that the equation
 $$5\times 2^{x-4}-3^y=-1$$
has or no  solutions, or I must look for a method to solve it. Thank you.

Comment: Catalan does not apply because $5\cdot 2^{x-4}$ is not a perfect power.

Comment: $(8/4)$ seems to be the only solution, but I do not know a proof yet. No further solution for $x\le 10^5$

Comment: maybe we have to solve an equation of form $3^y\equiv 1( \mod 2^{x-4} )$??

Comment: Usually, such equations are difficult to solve completely, but it is well possible that someone on this site finds a complete answer.

Comment: compare  various (elementary) answers at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1941354/elementary-solution-of-exponential-diophantine-equation-2x-3y-7/  They take a few steps but are just the same observations repeated.. Also, this method is not much changed by the extra factor of $5$

Answer (score 2):

Elementary proof. I learned the method at [Exponential Diophantine equation $7^y + 2 = 3^x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1551324/exponential-diophantine-equation-7y-2-3x/1551383#1551383)

We think that the largest answer is $5 \cdot 16 = 81 - 1. $ Write this as 
$5 \cdot 16 \cdot 2^x = 81 \cdot 3^y - 1.$ Subtract $80$ from both sides, 
$ 80 \cdot 2^x - 80 = 81 \cdot 3^y - 81.$ We reach
$$ 80 (2^x - 1) = 81 (3^y - 1).  $$
This is convenient; we will show that both $x,y$ must be zero. That is, ASSUME both $x,y \geq 1.$
From $2^x \equiv 1 \pmod {81}$ we get
$$ x \equiv 0 \pmod {54}. $$
It follows that $2^x - 1$ is divisible by $2^{54} - 1.$
$$ 2^{54 } - 1 = 3^4 \cdot 7 \cdot 19 \cdot 73 \cdot 87211 \cdot  262657
$$
Next, $3^y - 1$ is divisible by the large prime $262657$
From $3^y \equiv 1 \pmod {262657}$ we find
$$ y \equiv 0 \pmod {14592} $$ and especially
$$ y \equiv 0 \pmod {2^8}. $$
We do not need as much as $2^8 = 256,$ we really just need the corollary
$$ y \equiv 0 \pmod 8  $$
Next $3^y - 1$ is divisible by $3^8 - 1 = 32 \cdot 5 \cdot 41.$  This is the big finish, $3^y - 1$ is divisible by $32.$ Therefore $80 (2^x-1)$ is divisible by $32,$ so that $2^x - 1$ is even. This is impossible if $x \geq 1,$ and is the **contradiction** needed to say that, in
$$ 80 (2^x - 1) = 81 (3^y - 1) \; ,  $$
actually $x,y$ are both zero.

Comment: Thank you very much. frankly, I just started this method like you.

Answer (score 1):

With the two substitutions:
$$x-4=w$$
$$y=2z$$
We rearrange to:

$$5(2^w)=(3^z-1)(3^z+1)$$
So we want $z$ such that $$\bigg[3^z-1=5(2^a)\bigg] \text{ and } \bigg[3^z+1=2^b\bigg]$$ 
or
$$\bigg[3^z+1=5(2^a)\bigg] \text{ and } \bigg[3^z-1=2^b\bigg]$$

We can see $z=2$ (and thus $y=4$) satisfies the second line here. (which leads to $x=8$ as others conclude).

See if you can take it from here.

Comment: Can we deduce that is a unique solution?

Answer (score 1):

From $3^y\equiv1$ mod $5$, we see that $4\mid y$, so writing $y=4z$, we have

$$5\cdot2^{x-4}=3^{4z}-1=(3^{2z}+1)(3^{2z}-1)$$

Since $3^{2z}+1\equiv2$ mod $8$, we can only have $3^{2z}+1=2$ or $10$.  We can dismiss the first possibility (since it implies $z=0$, which gives $3^{2z}-1=0$). Thus $3^{2z}+1=10$, so $z=1$ and thus $5\cdot2^{x-4}=10\cdot8$ implies $x-4=4$. We find $(x,y)=(8,4)$ as the only solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try $x=8$ and $y=4$. Not sure if there are any other integer solutions.

Comment: Yes $(x,y)=(8,4)$ is a solution. How did you get the solution and is it unique?

Comment: Guess and check. Sorry =)

Comment: This is more a comment, it's good you found a solution but now you need to solve the question in full generality.

Comment: Can't comment since my rep is below 50 but you're right

Answer (score 0):

Solving for $y$ yields no solutions for $-3000\le x \le 3000$ but solving for $x$ does. WolframAlpha has a solution of $x$ in terms of $y$ [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=+solve+5%5Ctimes+2%5E%7Bx-4%7D-3%5Ey%2B1%3D0+for+x) and plugging this into a spreadsheet does yield one solution in this range.
$$5\times 2^{x-4}-3^y+1=0\implies 
x = \frac{\log(\frac{16(3^y - 1)}{5})}{\log(2)}\implies x=8\land y=4$$