# Find all positive integers $n$ and $m$ such that $(125\times2^n)-3^m=271$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Find all positive integers $n$ and $m$ such that $(125\times2^n)-3^m=271$

I have thought about this question for a long time and I can't seem to solve it. I realize that $271$ is a prime and so I'm tried to factor the LHS but couldn't. I came to the conclusion that n is odd and m is equivalent to $2$ modulo $4$ by using modulo $3$ and $5$ respectively. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Note;  $(n,m)=(3,6)$ is one solution

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I did realize that and I was able to solve for m and n when they were multiples of 3, but couldn't continue for other values.

Comment: Note that with $p=n-3$ and $q=m-6$ (small solutions can be dealt with easily) we have $1000\cdot 2^p-729\cdot 3^q=1000-729$ so that $1000\cdot (2^p-1)=729(3^q-1)$ - there are prospects here, and modulo $1000$ and $729$ you get a sparser set of possibilities than modulo $3$ and $5$.

Comment: @MarkBennet sure but that still doesn't look at all fun to try to solve

Comment: @MarkBennet  $q \equiv 0 \pmod {100},$ in particular $q \equiv 0 \pmod 4,$ then $3^q-1$ is divisible by $16,$ therefore $2^p - 1$ is even and $p=0$

Comment: @WillJagy you should write this out as an answer. This looks really nice

Answer (score 2):

I put a really difficult example of this method at [Finding solutions to the diophantine equation $7^a=3^b+100$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1946621/finding-solutions-to-the-diophantine-equation-7a-3b100/1946810#1946810)  including some links to easier examples and the place where I learned it; seems fair to give credit to the student who seems to have invented it, [Exponential Diophantine equation $7^y + 2 = 3^x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1551324/exponential-diophantine-equation-7y-2-3x/1551383#1551383)

From Mark Bennet, we reach
$$ 1000 (2^p - 1) = 729 (3^q - 1)  $$
The argument goes back and forth, this one is quick: we know
$$  3^q \equiv 1 \pmod 5 \; ,  $$
so that
$$ q \equiv 0 \pmod 4 \; .  $$
However, then $3^4 - 1 = 81 - 1 = 80 = 16 \cdot 5,$ so
$$ 3^q - 1 \equiv 0 \pmod {16}.  $$
Now $$  16 | 1000 (2^p-1) \; , $$
so $2^p - 1$ is even and $$  p=0$$

Comment: Nicely done. I was falling asleep at the screen and didn't follow i through ...

Comment: So a little more generally than the case in the link, if $ap^M-bq^N=r$ has the solution $ap^m-bq^n=r$ we can eliminate $r$ to obtain $ap^m(p^{M-m}-1)=bq^n(q^{N-n}-1)$ and this method can be used to investigate 'large' solutions. I am now wondering what might be known which would throw further light on this procedure and when it will work and if it ever fails.

Comment: @MarkBennet thanks. Gottfried came up with a different view of this. I'm not sure it ever fails, but I attempted one where the numbers got too big to continue with my computer/software. The way I do it is pretty random looking, go through all prime factors of some $p^d - 1,$ whee $d$ is large enough to make $p^d-1$ enormous. I have no idea how to predict the prime factor that should be picked for the next step...