# Exponential diophantine equation $2^x+7^y=9^z$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, exponential-diophantine-equations

The challenge is to solve this equation $2^{x}+7^{y}=9^{z}$ in positive integers. The obvious solution is $x=y=z=1$. Using brute force, I found $3$ possible solutions:
\begin{eqnarray*}
(x_1,y_1,z_1)&=&(3,0,1),\\
(x_2,y_2,z_2)&=&(1,1,1)\\
(x_3,y_3,z_3)&=&(5,2,2).\\
\end{eqnarray*}
There are no other natural solutions for $z≤10000$.

It seems that the equation $2^{x}+7^{y}=9^{z}$ has no other solutions in natural numbers. How can this be proven?

Comment: Technically one of your solutions doesn't take $y$ to be a _positive_ integer.

Comment: @J.G. Good point, but that doesn't change much.

Comment: [True](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is easy to verify computationally that considering the equation modulo $17043520$ implies that it has the only solutions:
$$(x,y,z)\in \{ (1, 1, 1),\ (3, 0, 1),\ (5, 2, 2)\}.$$

I refer to the [discussion at AOPS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h48431) on how to find such a modulus. The one I mentioned above may be not the smallest possible, but it does the job.

**UPDATE.** As established by brute-force, the smallest working modulus here is $128320$.

PS. For the theory behind such equations, see the paper:

> J. L. Brenner, L. L. Foster "Exponential Diophantine equations".
> Pacific J. Math. Volume 101, Number 2 (1982), 263-301.
> http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1102724775

Answer (score 7):

**Hint 1:** If $x>1$ then reducing mod $4$ shows that $y$ is even, say $y=2v$, and so
$$2^x=(3^z+7^v)(3^z-7^v).$$
**Hint 2:** It follows that $3^z-2^{x-2}=1$.

Comment: Modulo $80$, we get $x=4k+5$, $y=4l+2$, $z=2m$. It is important that $y$ is even. It doesn't matter what $z$ is, since $9$ is already a square. I also considered your idea, but did not go far.

Comment: @Cornifer I have added another hint.

Comment: Why cannot there be an infinite number of solutions w $x=1$?

Comment: @John Omielan why cant $x=1$?

Comment: Hi @John Omielan, I knew that, what I meant was, does anyone have a proof that there are not an *infinite* number of sol'ns for $x=1$. I cited you specifically because you are great at figuring out the challenging number-theory problems on here :)

Comment: @Mike Sorry about misunderstanding your earlier comment. Also, thanks for the compliment. Although I sometimes can determine how to solve a challenging problem quite quickly (although it usually takes some time, and occasionally an inordinate amount of time!), I don't see anything particularly simple & obvious here. Nonetheless, my initial approach would be something like what is done in the AOPS link in Max Alekseyev's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4296101/602049). Perhaps later, if this is not fully solved then & I have some time, I'll try to finish it myself.

Comment: @Mike To clarify my last sentence, note Max Alekseyev's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4296101/602049) does fully solve this. I meant determining a simpler solution than using modulo $17043520$, in particular one which can be fully explained & understood within a reasonable size answer.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Thanks for the tip! I'd say it's obvious that there's no solution with $x=2$, but this covers it explicitly and looks cleaner.

Answer (score 4):

here is a method I learned from [Exponential Diophantine equation $7^y + 2 = 3^x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1551324/exponential-diophantine-equation-7y-2-3x/1551383#1551383)  and polished. I have answered many questions of the form $A^u - B^v = C$  for given positive integers $A,B,C$

This answer finishes $x=1.$

The following shows that, with $x = 1,$  the largest solution to $9^z - 7^y = 2 $   is $z=y=1.$  First, write $9^z - 9 = 7^y -7$  Next introduce non-negative integers $p,q$  with
$$ 9(9^p - 1) = 7 (7^q - 1), $$
**ASSUME**  $p,q \geq 1$  and reach a contradiction.   We alternate steps, each is a calculation.

$$ 7 | 9^p -1  \Longrightarrow   \; \;  3 | p$$
$$ 9^3 - 1 = 2^3 \cdot 7 \cdot 13 $$
$$ 13 | 7^q -1  \Longrightarrow   \; \;  12 | q$$
$$ 7^{12} - 1 = 2^5 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 5^2   \cdot 13 \cdot 19 \cdot 43 \cdot 181 $$

$$ 19 | 9^p -1  \Longrightarrow   \; \;  9 | p$$
$$ 9^9 - 1 = 2^3 \cdot 7 \cdot 13 \cdot  19 \cdot 37 \cdot 757 $$
$$ 37 | 7^q -1  \Longrightarrow   \; \;  9 | q$$
$$ 7^{9} - 1 = 2 \cdot 3^3  \cdot 19 \cdot 37 \cdot 1063 $$

This number divides $9 (9^p - 1). $  In particular, $27 |  9 (9^p - 1).$
This **CONTRADICTS** the assumption that $p > 0$

Answer (score 2):

This is a PARTIAL answer. What remains to show is that there are not an infinite number of solutions for $x=1$. Assume $x\ge 3$. Then as in Conner's answer,
$$2^x = (3^z-7^v)(3^z+7^v).$$

This gives for some positive integer $a$ the equation
$$2^a(3^z-7^v)=(3^z+7^v).$$

Rearranging terms gives
$$(2^a-1)3^z = (2^a+1)7^v,$$

Note that this implies that $a$ must also be at least 3. So this gives $2^a+1=3^z$. As $a$ is at least $3$ [because one can check that there are no solutions to the above equation for $a \in \{1,2\}$], it follows that $2^a+1=3^z$ and thus in particular $3^z$ must be $1$ mod $8$, and so it follows that $z$ must be even, which gives

$$(3^{z/2}-1)(3^{z/2}+1) = 2^a,$$
which implies both $3^{z/2}-1$, $3^{z/2}+1$, must be powers of $2$. As they differ by only $2$, this is possible only if $z=2$ and $a=3$. So if $x$ is at least $3$, then $v$ must be $1$ and thus $y$ must be $2$. Thus $x$ must be $5$ and $z=2$.

Comment: FYI, here's an alternate way to solve for $x \ge 2$ the equation $2^x = (3^z - 7^v)(3^z + 7^v)$. First, note both factors on the right are positive, even and powers of $2$. Thus, $3^z - 7^v = 2^a$ and $3^z + 7^v = 2^b$ with $a \lt b$ and $a + b = x$. Adding the $2$ equations gives $2(3^z) = 2^a + 2^b = 2^a(1 + 2^{b - a})$. Equating the even and odd parts gives $2 = 2^a \; \to \; a = 1$ and $3^z = 1 + 2^{b - a} \implies 3^z - 2^{b - a} = 1$. If $b - a = 1 \; \to \; b = 2$, then $x = 3$ and $z = 1$. ...

Comment: (cont.) Otherwise, with $b - a \gt 1$ and $z \gt 1$, there are proofs here, plus [Mihăilescu's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture) can be used, to show the only solution is $z = 2$ and $b - a = 3 \; \to \; b = 4$, so $x = 5$.

Answer (score 2):

Refer to Henri Cohen's *Number Theory Volume I: Tools for Diophantine Equations*
p. $410-411$ and also $461$ for exercise $35$.

For $x = 1$, the equation becomes $2+7^{y}=9^{z} \implies 2+7^{y}=(3^z)^2 \implies (3^{z})^{2}=7^{y}+2.$

On page $410$ we have **$6.7$ The Equation**:

$y^{2} = x^{n}+t$ for $-100 \leq t \leq -1$ and $n$ even, $t \not\equiv 1 \pmod {8}$, and $t$ squarefree.

By page $419$, the above result is generalized to include odd $n$ as well, showing that each equation satisfying the above has a finite number of solutions, listed in a table in the book.

It is indicated that using the reasoning of the proofs of recent theorems, this result can be extended to $|t| \leq 100.$

It seems a lot of directly related material is in Chapter $6.7$ of this book and the in-text references, as well as the prerequisite material contained within, however it is clear much of it is "left to the reader" to organize as a proof for exercise $35$ which I am personally unable to do myself at this time.

Comment: Not sure why I get a downvote, it is a direct reference to a generalization to the equation.  One answer just writes it is easy to verify, and the other two don't consider $x=1$, but I get the downvote only. Ok.

Comment: I upvoted this, because I didn't think it deserved a downvote either. The reference does look interesting. But for questions like these, what is the more satisfying--and expected--for most of us, are reasonably *self-contained* answers as opposed to referencing another source.

Comment: there is also a way tyo do $x=1$   with simple calculations, I put an answer.