# Positive integer solutions to $a^x-b^y=2$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, exponentiation

Does anybody know the all positive integer solution of
$$
a^x-b^y=2
$$
under the condition
$$
x \geq 2, y\geq2
$$

I didn't find any solution without 
$$
x=5,y=3,a=2,b=3 
$$

Comment: $3^3-5^2=2$ is one.

Comment: Related: [Solutions to $7^a+2=3^b$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1007733), [Solutions to $x^{2}-7^{y}=2$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/508714).

Answer (score 2):

See [Catalan's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture) (Mihăilescu's theorem) for $a^x-b^y=1$, where it's also written about the general $a^x-b^y=n$.

https://oeis.org/A076427 says there's exactly one solution when $a^x,b^y<10^{18}$.

The solution is $(a,b,x,y)=(3,5,3,2)$.

Comment: Why is the number of solution is exactly one?

Comment: This is the only known solution. It is an open problem as to whether it is the only solution.